# Audible Database Structure

Tags: database, database-design, architecture, relational-database

I have a class project that I need to show what kind of
**relational databases used in audible app**.
I don't have much background in this field and I don't even know how to start it.
Databases that came to my mind:

1. **Users table**: username, full_name, email, phone, password, subscription
2. **User Library table**: username, book_title, date_added, location, status, favorites (yes/no)
3. **Books table**: Author, Narrator,  Lenght, Publisher, version (abridged/unabridged), Language, Rating, Release date, Summary (text)
4. **Book Rating table:** book_title, username, rating, title, review, date

I'm not sure if this is the right way and if I used the right columns and I would love to get some help and guidance with that.

Comment: It depends on your needs. I just made some corrections to the design you made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Reader**: UserID, UserFullName, UserLogin, Email, Phone, Password
2. **Author** : AuthorID, AuthorFullName, Email, Fax, Phone, HomeAddress ..
3. **Book**: BookID, Title, Narrator,  NumberOfPages, Language, Summary, AddedByID
4. **BookAuthorPulisher** : AuthorID, BookID, PublisherID, Version, ReleaseDate //since a book can be written by many authors and can be
   published by many publishers
5. **Publisher** : PublisherID, PublisherName, Phone, Fax, Email, Website..
6. **BookRating** : BookID, ReaderID, Rating, Review, RatingDate